# Symbiosis tag please?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

At the root of every ecology is a biome filled with co-dependant organisms. Things which just evolved together over time - frogs hiding in trees, Egrets riding on oxen, ramoras riding on sharks, cows using rumen bacteria to digest grass, etc.

I did not see a symbiosis tag in here for developing co-dependent relationships between organisms. **As of this post, I have added one. Please feel free to design your creatures' mutual relationships with this tag!**

This is too broad for biology, there is not necessarily a biological reason for symbiosis. Sometimes the organisms are smart enough to just know what works best, like a tree frog and a tree.

At this writing there are 280 questions in [biology] asking about symbiosis in one form or another, and they always combine it with another almost arbitrary tag which wastes 2 of you 5 tags. I think it warrants a tag.

Comment: I could create it but I'm not going to do the editing to add it to the 280 questions. You only need 300 rep for tag creation anyway, I'm sure you can get there fast enough :)

Comment: Can't the editing go into a review queue? This isn’t the first time a tag has split?

Comment: It's something that has to be done manually. Any time someone gets something like this into their heads they have to get down and edit all those posts by hand.